# Should tags for specific software products be permitted?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just encountered the tag [lightroom](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightroom). The question using it makes pretty clear what it stands for: [Alternative to Adobe Photoshop Lightroom?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/291/185)

My point here is: Should we support tags for a specific product? Or should we rather remove them from their questions, so they get cleaned up by the automated maintenance?

Same question applies to manufacturer tags. Current example: [samsung](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, sure, there can be tags for specific products, such as [windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) or [vim](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim). These tags are about finding software that interacts with that product: a program that runs on Windows, a Vim plugin. The X tag does not mean “[alternative for X](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software)”.

[lightroom](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightroom) (better worded as [adobe-lightroom](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-lightroom)) would be a fine tag for an Adobe Lightroom plugin request. On a question looking for an alternative, it is not appropriate. [samsung](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung) on [Cell phone emulation to capture screen action?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/337/cell-phone-emulation-to-capture-screen-action) is appropriate in this sense, but it is just too vague to be meaningful.

Comment: Then you are saying that both tags in their current questions are not valid? IMO they are meaningless as don't add anything to the question.

Comment: Thanks, Gilles! Makes perfect sense to me concerning the first part. Though I do not see any sense for the 'samsung' tag at all: they build phones with different OS (Android, Bada, ...), Smart TVs, hard disks, memory chips... What help should it be? At Android.SE we often find this "Meta-Tag" ("I have a Samsung device...", but "Samsung" has no relation to the issue). Luckily, this specific tag will be purged soon (not used by any question).

Comment: @Braiam Yes, and I edited them both out. On that Samsung-related question, [tag:samsung-android-phone] would have made sense, but it's overspecific.

Answer (score 0):

No. We are not experts in recommending software *similar to Lightroom*, but *image editors* (which would be a good tag). Nor we are supposed to be experts in software that can be used with samsung but software to emulate different kind of stuff (the question ask for emulators). So yeah, tags representing manufacturers or end-products should not be allowed and instead use the kind of software you want like "emulator" or "photography editor" or "image editors" or "vector editor", etc.