# Burn the "plugin" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently 19 questions have the [plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin) tag.

I think we should get rid of this tag. Whenever a plugin (or extension, or add-on, …) for a specific software is needed, the question should be tagged with a [tag for this specific software](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/301/60).

So when a question has the tags [eclipse](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) and [plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin), the [eclipse](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) tag alone already implies that a plugin (or maybe a compatible software) for Eclipse is needed. The question title/body can/should make this clear explicitly.

(If we agree, I could retag those questions.)

Comment: Checking questions currently using it, this sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: see also [That early meta-topic on a tagging guide](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/467/can-we-agree-on-a-tagging-guide#468) (@unor I know you know about it but for others I figured it might give some background)

Comment: Maybe the only acceptable use of "plugin" would be for questions that ask for a plugin architecture: *I want to allow people to write plugins for my app, what library/framework would help me do this?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All questions that had the [plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin) tag are now retagged.

If tags for specific softwares [should](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/869/60) or [should not](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/885/60) have a "-plugin" suffix, can be discussed separately:
**[“-plugin” suffix for specific-software tags?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/917/60)**

Answer (score 1):

I agree, and more generally, I think we should rename all the `-plugin(s)` tags into their parent name. A tag like [wordpress-plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin) means “I'm looking for a Wordpress plugin that …” — but really the question is “I'm trying to accomplish … with Wordpress”. Even if the answers are expected to be “use this plugin”, the question is not really about plugins, it's about Wordpress.

And if you assume that everything about Wordpress is about plugins, then the `-plugin` part of the tag is redundant and should be removed. Either way, `-plugin` is pure noise.

Comment: I'm going to have to disagree with you here. This is Software Recommendations, and the only WordPress questions that would be on-topic are questions looking for a plugin recommendation. Questions about how to accomplish a particular task in WordPress without a plugin are for Wordpress.SE.

Comment: @BenMiller But the software that solves the problem is not necessarily a WordPress plugin!

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused.  What other software would it be?  If it isn't a WordPress plugin, then the question wouldn't be tagged with the "wordpress" tag.  The question "How do I do X in WordPress?" is off-topic here.  The question "Which plugin should I use to do X in WordPress?" is off-topic at WordPress.SE and on-topic here.  Can you give an example of a WordPress software recommendation question that is on-topic here and not about a plugin?

Comment: @BenMiller Q: I need a WordPress plugin to prevent DoS… A: You can't do that with a plugin, you need a proxy. Or Q: I need a WordPress plugin to display pink text. A: You don't need a plugin for that, set `text_color=pink` in the configuration. It's not all about plugins. Even if it was, having `-plugin` in the tag name is just noise — if “If it isn't a WordPress plugin, then the question wouldn't be tagged with the "wordpress" tag” then the right tag name is “wordpress” and not “wordpress-plugin” since the `-plugin` part carries no useful information.

Comment: hmm I can definitely see this argument however... if you follow it logically wouldn't the same argument apply to [tag:chrome-extensions] too? Which I don't think it should so considering that I do prefer with the wordpress-plugin tag if the question is looking for a plugin for wordpress.

Comment: @NickWilde Sure, that tag should be [tag:chrome]. Again, what matters is that you want to interact with Chrome, and if the answer is a plugin or a bookmarklet instead of an extension, that doesn't change the question.

Comment: @Gilles Both of your examples are plugin questions.  The fact that the best answer might be recommending a solution other than a plugin is not relevant to the tags.  If you prefer not to see "-plugin" in the tag name, that is fine (I prefer to see it.)  But the argument that we need to remove it to allow for non-plugin questions is not valid on this site.

Comment: @BenMiller: See, for example, the question [Offline WordPress post editor/creator](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2696/60). The OP is looking for a solution that works *with* WordPress (it needs to upload posts into the WordPress installation), but it can’t be a plugin (hence I created the [tag:wordpress] tag because [tag:wordpress-plugin] would be misleading).

Comment: @unor That is a good example; another would be a question about mobile apps interfacing with the Wordpress admin. However, you could argue that these questions are really a separate class of questions from the plugin questions, deserving their own tag. And for other "-plugin" tags it might be harder to come up with examples like these.

Comment: I created a discussion: [“-plugin” suffix for specific-software tags?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/917/60)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the [plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin) tag is not very helpful.  Instead, I propose that the questions be tagged with a tag named "*software*-plugin".  For example, all of the WordPress plugin questions are currently tagged with [wordpress-plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin).  The [eclipse](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) tag should get renamed [eclipse-plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin).

Using this naming convention, we would eliminate an unnecessary tag (there is no reason that all plugin questions for any platform need to be grouped together), and yet it will still be obvious to anyone looking at the tags that the question is looking for a plugin.

Comment: It should be the other way round: we should rename [tag:wordpress-plugin] to [tag:wordpress]. At best the `-plugin` part doesn't convey any useful information; at worst it leads the answers into recommending a plugin rather than some other solution (some problems may be better solved with a different configuration, a proxy, …).

Comment: @Gilles Non-plugin WordPress questions are for WordPress.SE.

Comment: Of course, but that has nothing to do with what I wrote.