# "-plugin" suffix for specific-software tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

*(Gilles brought this up in [his answer](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/885/60) to the question [Burn the “plugin” tag](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/867/60))*

If a question asks for a solution that is required to work with a specific software, it should be tagged with a tag for this software.

Currently, we have two kinds of such tags:

- `foobar`
  Examples: [wordpress](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress), [eclipse](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclipse), [mediawiki](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mediawiki)
- `foobar-plugin` / `foobar-plugins` / `foobar-extension`
  Examples: [wordpress-plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin), [firefox-extension](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefox-extension), [vim-plugins](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim-plugins)

We should be consistent and decide:

**Append `-plugin`/`-extension`/`-module`, or not? Or have both?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think we should **omit these suffixes**.

#### Not everything is a plugin(/module/extension/…)

There are cases where a solution is required to work *with* a software, but it doesn’t necessarily have to be a plugin (or similar).

Example question: [Offline WordPress post editor/creator](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2696/60) - Here a solution is required to work with WordPress, but it can’t be a WordPress plugin. So tagging this with [wordpress-plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin) is obviously wrong, so we need a [wordpress](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) tag.

But when we need a [wordpress](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) tag anyway, …

#### … what do we gain by having an additional *-plugin* tag?

Experts in WordPress plugins are very likely also experts in WordPress, and they probably know cooperating tools.

Of course there are cases where a user explicitly needs a plugin (and doesn’t want to use a separate tool), but this is information which can be specified in the question. I don’t think this case necessitates an additional tag.

#### Some programs have plugins *and* extensions

For example, Mozilla Firefox has "add-ons" and "plugins". Following the suffix model, we would need three tags:

- [firefox](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefox) (for things not being plugins/add-ons),
- [firefox-plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefox-plugin) (for plugins),
- [firefox-add-on](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefox-add-on) (for add-ons aka. extensions).

I guess in many cases, users don’t care if a solution is technically a plugin, an extension, a user script or a different tool. The tag [firefox](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefox) could cover all these cases.

---

So I propose to omit any suffixes and use the software name as tag value:

- [chrome-extension](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome-extension) → [chrome](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome) ([done!](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/939/60))
- [firefox-extension](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefox-extension) → [firefox](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefox) ([done!](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/939/60))
- [wordpress-plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin) → [wordpress](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) ([done!](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/939/60))
- [vim-plugins](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim-plugins) → [vim](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim) (done!)
- [notepad++-plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b-plugin) → [notepad++](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b) (done!)
- [bukkit-plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bukkit-plugin) → [bukkit](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bukkit) (done, previously retagged by *aman207*)
- [visual-studio-plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-plugin) → [visual-studio](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) (done!)

Answer (score 2):

Merged and renamed:

- [anki-plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anki-plugin) → [anki](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anki) (1)
- [chrome-extension](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome-extension) → [chrome](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome) (58, there were only 2 [chrome](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome) question: [1](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10666/web-app-to-count-how-many-tabs-i-have-open) explicitly not satisfiable by an extension and [1](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10311/oneliner-style-addon-for-chrome) looking for an extension)
- [firefox-extension](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefox-extension) → [firefox](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefox) (21, there was only [1](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10327/tool-to-take-screenshot-of-a-specific-html-element-of-a-webpage) [firefox](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefox) question and it's a problem that's likely to be solved by an extension)
- [netbeans-plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netbeans-plugin) → [netbeans](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netbeans) (1)
- [opencart-plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opencart-plugin) → [opencart](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opencart) (1)
- [photoshop-plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photoshop-plugin) → [photoshop](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photoshop) (1)
- [wordpress-plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin) → [wordpress](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) (18, of which 4 had both tags)

Experimentally, an overwhelming majority of questions about X for which an X-plugin or X-extension tag existed were tagged with the -plugin/-extension variant, whether being a plugin/extension in the strict sense was a strict requirement or not. There was no meaningful difference in usage between the X and X-plugin/extension tags. So having the distinct tags did not serve any purpose.