# How do we fix incorrect instructions presented to visitors?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The description for the [web-browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browser) tag instructs visitors to:

*"Use this tag when asking for recommendations relating to web browser software and web browser add-ons. If you are specifically looking for a Firefox or Chrome add-on/extension/plugin, use the tag [firefox-extension] or [chrome-extension] instead."*

Trouble is, neither recommended tag exists.

How do we fix this and who does it?

What do we do about tags for existing questions that are about browser add-ons, extensions, or plugins?

Comment: I removed the tag "bug" as bugs are for bugs in the software, rather then bugs in user-generated-content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should fix that description to use [firefox](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefox) and [chrome](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome) respectively. That is what is used in reality.

Note: I did the edit. It needs to be approved, yet.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it Angelo.

Answer (score 2):

Tag descriptions (tag wikis and tag wiki excerpts) can be edited by anyone. If you have less than [4000 reputation](/help/privileges/trusted-user), your edit will be reviewed by other users before it goes live.

The tag wiki was written before [we standardized add-on/plugin/extension tags](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/917/plugin-suffix-for-specific-software-tags) and we forgot to update the [web-browsers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browsers) tag wiki. [Angelo Fuchs](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1131) has now [updated](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/3195) it.

Comment: Thanks.  Where does one edit the tag descriptions?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Click on the tag, then click “improve tag wiki” (or “help us create it” if there's no wiki summary yet).

Comment: Thanks Gilles.  I didn't realize the 'wiki' was where the descriptions came from.