# Why removed "client" tag everywhere?

Tags: discussion, tags

Someone removed all "client" tags, can he explain why?

Comment: That tag does sound meaningless.

Comment: Well, for example someone wants to find all questions about ftp clients but not servers.

Comment: Also there is a desctop-client tag.

Comment: It looks like client was replaced with desktop client. Client on its own is a very unspecific tag.

Answer (score 3):

I removed the *client* tag from all questions that had it two days ago (not sure if more questions had it and someone else removed it from them before), which were these 5 (an amount where I thought a preceding Meta discussion was not needed) IIRC:

- [Torrent client with continuous file download](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10966/torrent-client-with-continuous-file-download)
- [VPN with straightforward, reliable configuration directions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/vpn-with-straightforward-reliable-configuration-directions)
- [Looking for a IRC bouncer / client combo](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10940/looking-for-a-irc-bouncer-client-combo)
- [Torrent client for a NAS](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10928/torrent-client-for-a-nas)
- [IRC client with sound options for each channel separately](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3089/irc-client-with-sound-options-for-each-channel-separately)

A big part of our questions ask for clients, hence all of these *could* have used this tag, but only 5 of these questions used it. So it seems there is not much use for this generic tag, and it isn’t really useful if only such a very small fraction of so many applicable questions use it in the first place.
And I think it’s too generic (similar to the former [*plugin* tag](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/867/60)), *client* on its own doesn’t mean much.

I can see that it is useful to use tags in the search function to find only questions asking for, e.g., BitTorrent clients instead of BitTorrent servers. But, if there is need for it (which I’m not sure about), I think this should be made possible with a specific tag, not a generic tag. Example: [email-client](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email-client).
Or, maybe, by having specific server tags instead (assuming that client questions are more numerous than server questions), so these can be exluded in the search when looking for clients?