# Burn the "plug-in" tag, too

Tags: discussion, tags

We got rid of the [plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin) tag some years ago ([Burn the "plugin" tag](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/867/60)).

Now there is the [plug-in](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plug-in) tag.

As it’s used on more than 20 questions, I guess it would be best that a mod deletes the tag, instead of editing (and pushing to the front page) all these questions to remove the tag.

(I edited the only question that had no other tag in addition, so now no question would end up being untagged.)

Comment: Thanks unor.  It's interesting that this tag keeps on coming up as a useful tag, including in questions from some of our most experienced community members.  Overall, I agree with the original logic of why it was removed, but given that community members are finding it useful, I want to give it some careful thought before deleting the tag.  Iggy and Nicolas, what do you think?  Community, your thoughts?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: I am for burninating it too. The consensus has not changed at https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/867/60

Comment: I can see good arguments for keeping it. For a non-technical end user, a plug-in is just another app (that lets his app do something more). For a technical user, we can look on it somewhat like a library

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: Given the consensus on the linked question, and the votes on this question (+4 / -0), is burning the tag warranted? Or can this discussion be bumped somehow to attract more community input?