# What should our /about contain?

Tags: discussion, tour-page

I've taken a first go at the customizable parts of the very first page users are supposed to read on the site — [the tour page (formerly known as /about)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/about), based on the [guidelines we've established so far](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/faq).

We can customize two sections: “Ask about…” and “Don't ask about…”. Here's the current content (we [can't edit the title](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/617/allow-moderators-to-customize-the-first-line-of-the-editable-parts-of-about)).

> #### Ask about…
>
> Good software recommendation requests have two components:
>
> - A purpose — a task to accomplish, a user story
> - Some objective requirements — a minimum set of features
>
> Please read our [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).
>
> We request that answers demonstrate how the recommended product meets the requirement and is suitable for the intended purpose. Please read our [answer quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality) for more information.
>
> #### Don't ask about…
>
> - Requests for lists of software with no defined purpose — our objective is to find the best fit for a task.
>
>   - Questions without concrete requirements — if some potential answer would lack a critical feature, we need to know.
>
> If you're [asking for alternatives](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software), be sure to describe the features you're using and why what you have isn't up for the task.

Feedback welcome.

Comment: **Related**: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/348/what-should-our-documentation-contain

Answer (score 3):

Can the About please include whether web apps are OK to ask for, or whether this site is limited to desktop (or mobile?) software?

I [had my hand slapped by @jonsca](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60568/what-online-photo-storage-can-map-pictures-based-on-exif-gps-data) for posting a web app question on webapps.SE, and I find it difficult to determine what the scope of SR.SE is, starting from its About page.

Comment: Yes, and about libraries as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think the way the "Ask about" section is formulated isn't quite correct.

The first bullet-point is about when to ask a question, and the second is about how to ask it

> ### Ask about
>
> You should ask a question when you have a purpose in mind, something
>   you're willing to accomplish in a specific way. Be sure to remember
>   to:
>
> - list specific requirements
> - follow our [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)
>
> This will allow others to give [quality answers](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) to your questions.