# Allow moderators to customize the first line of the editable parts of /about

Tags: feature-request, tour-page

I [took a first go at filling the moderator-editable parts](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/616/what-should-our-about-contain) of [/about](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour).

It seems to me that the “Ask about…” section doesn't really work as a bullet point list of topics. What I'd like to write is

> #### Ask questions that define both …
>
> - a purpose — a task to accomplish, a user story
> - some objective requirements — a minimum set of features

Starting with “Ask about…” forces a format that doesn't work well here.

Similarly, I'd like to modify the wording “Don't ask about…”.

Please allow moderators to customize these lines as well.