# Please update the Help Center's "What topics can I ask about here?"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tour-page, help-center

The SE podcast summary lured me to Software Recommendations. I've had a [question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1747/1008) for a while now that my gut told me would be on topic.

As a moderately active SE citizen I wanted to be careful though (remembering the "[no shopping list questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)" mantra), so I went to the [Help Center's "What topics can I ask about here?" page](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to check before asking. That page is empty(ish) though, but most of the info I'd expect on that page is listed in ["How to ask and answer software recommendation questions - aka 'The Ground Rules'"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/455/1008).

I <strike>think</strike> hope more people are cautious and visit the help center before firing questions, especially on this new site. It might be wise, if possible, to update the Help Center with at least a link to meta or even the relevant subset of info from that question.

Comment: Yeah, this is absolutely something we need to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>[`/about`](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/about)</s> [`/tour`](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) (the two point to the same thing) is kind of the new `/faq#on-topic`, it's a lot more discoverable than `/help/on-topic`. Nevertheless you're right, we should update that. I've added content similar to [our `/about`](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/616/what-should-our-about-contain). Feedback welcome.

Comment: It *is* more discoverable, but very generic. The on-topic section was exactly what I was looking for, and now contains enough info to find out if a question I have is a fit for SR.SE. Thx!