# Software to make something like <link>

Tags: discussion, scope

We often get questions like:

> I must implement such animations (preferably integrated with React): <link> Any idea which library is best to do?
>
> I like the images at <link>, with what Linux software can I create images like that?

Are such questions OK, and if not, how to transform them into great questions?

Different from this question: [Software like <link>](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ask for an alternative to some software](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software)

Comment: @JanDoggen: Consider the question "*I like the images at <link>, with what Linux software can I create images like that?*". It is not asking for an alternative, actually it is not even citing any software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such questions are not OK, they will be closed if not fixed quickly.

**Rule: Do not force people to click links.**

Your question must be 100% understandable without clicking any link, by any IT expert in your field.

Benefits:

- Your question becomes searchable, and thus more useful to people who have the same requirements.
- More objective definition of requirements. Imagine you show [Mona Lisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mona_Lisa) to 100 people, and say "I want the same kind of thing". You will get 100 different interpretations of what you actually meant. Maybe you meant "half-length portrait of a woman" or maybe you meant "small-sized oil painting using the sfumato technique".
- Less time wasted by potential answerers, thus more/better answers.
- More enjoyable website for visitors.
- No broken links.

If necessary also post an image or screenshot, but even if you do, also describe your requirements with words.

Comment: Well done.  Thank you for posting this! :)