# Nominate temporary moderators for this site here

Tags: discussion, moderation

> The provisional moderators were appointed. For more information, see here: [Pro Tem Moderators... Activate](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/608/pro-tem-moderators-activate?cb=1)

---

### How do you become a provisional moderator for this site?

Soon after the site launches into "public beta," the Community Team will appoint provisional moderators from this community until the community is ready to hold its own elections (once it graduates from beta).

**Deep engagement in the community's development** is required for all temporary moderator candidates. All potential candidates must:

> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
> - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).
>
> Bonus points for:
>
> - Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
> - Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
> - Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.
>
> Candidates will be contacted and three of them will be selected to act
>   as provisional Moderators until the community holds formal elections
>   after the Beta period. Besides the normal abilities of a Moderator,
>   they will:
>
> 1. Have access to a special chat room where we will collectively work through the challenges of moderation and community self-policing.
> 2. Organize the process of selecting the site’s attributes (domain names, design issues, the [help center], etc.).
> 3. Rally community support and drive the mission of getting publicity for the site.
>
> Essentially, **they will have the ear of the Stack Exchange team for
>   anything we can do to help their sites succeed!**

### Nominating users to serve as moderators for the beta

For each user that you would like to nominate,

- post an answer containing the URLs to both of the user's **main and meta profiles on this site**
- optionally, link to the user's **Area 51 profile** or a profile from another site, or add a reason why you'd like him/her to moderate during beta
- **self-nominations** (i.e. posting your own profiles) are allowed and even encouraged
- post each user as a separate answer, and add multiple answers if you wish to nominate multiple users

Additionally, if someone nominates *you*, please **edit the answer** to indicate your approval (or declination). Optionally, add a paragraph or two about yourself.

If you downvote a particular nomination, you are encouraged to **share why** you did so in the comments, though you are not required to do so. Optionally, you may do the same for upvotes.

For more information, see [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

Comment: It's great that you're taking the reins like this, but we generally don't look at appointing moderators until a couple of weeks after switching to public beta (though, we're watching _now_ to see who stands out as good candidates)

Comment: I've also noticed something. When I first posted this, there were only 25 other discussions, yet there are currently 86 other [meta-tag:discussion]s!

Comment: World Engineer deleted his answer. Anyone know why he retracted his nomination? Too many negative votes, or what?

Comment: @gparyani Much as I want him as a mod here, it's not really worth speculating about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pro Tem Moderators... Activate](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/608/pro-tem-moderators-activate)

Comment: This question was just [tweeted](http://twitter.com/#!/StackSoftRecs/status/439164993029021696) an hour ago.

Comment: @TimPost still looking for some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to nominate myself

[image: profile for Nick Wilde at Software Recommendations Stack Exchange, Q&A for people seeking specific software recommendations]

[image: profile for Nick Wilde at Software Recommendations Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people seeking specific software recommendations]


[profile for Nick Wilde on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/454046.png?theme=dark](http://stackexchange.com/users/454046)

During the private beta I ended up as the 8th most active member and the 7th highest rep; so I should be fairly recognizable to any who were in the private beta and any of all our new members who read back through answers and questions. I have been a member of SO for a bit over 2 1/2 years; mostly I have been a lurker getting the information I need although if I see an question that I can answer with fairly high quality then I'll definitely answer. As well as a reasonable number of answers I have asked a couple questions in the SE network (not counting here).

I also have experience moderating in a few different (relatively small) forums for PyFFI/Niftools for example and as a respected programmer/modder/community member of the Bethesda ElderScrolls modding community.

I will always try to improve posts before closing but I do not have any problem with taking solid action if the situation warrants.

(Comments are always appreciated even if negative for any of my posts - I will truly appreciate it and take it as a lesson/an area that I need to improve on/whatever is appropriate).

Nick

Comment: I wonder, why the downvotes?

Comment: I **always** wonder that if no comments are given. This makes two posts today that I've had commentless downvotes :( To my mind no matter how negative, comments = can be improved (yes in some cases the only improvement possible may be deletion but I'd rather hear that than have no comment)

Comment: No one bothers to explain their rationale no matter how much I ask them.

Comment: I generally don't explain +1 but most often I will explain downs (exception being if there are already comments that adequately explain the problems)

Comment: @NickWilde I edited into the question to ask for rationales for votes.

Comment: "Anyone who hasn't seen one of my posts or comments on this beta is living under a rock " is certainly *downvote-worthy* and not a great way to start a campaign. I decided to look at your answers first though, and liked a few of them, so no downvote.

Comment: There is no obligation to explain downvotes. And, frankly, when it's opinions about people (and their capabilities), I find it very inappropriate to request an explanation.

Comment: I certainly am not saying there is an obligation; however it is a nicety that can lead to improvements - after putting my a way to privately contact me I did get some responses which have let me make some improvements.

Comment: @Paul For the private beta it was true (at the last day I was 8th most active and 7th highest rep); now that it is the public beta though I should remove it since with the influx my contributions will no doubt be a much lower percentage.

Comment: Accepting your answer to make sure that no one overlooks your nomination.

Answer (score 32):

[image: profile for Undo at Software Recommendations Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people seeking specific software recommendations]

[image: profile for Undo at Software Recommendations Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people seeking specific software recommendations]
[profile for Undo on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1703573.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1703573/undo)

I would like to nominate Undo, as he seems very helpful and not obnoxious even though he has a lot of reputation.

Main: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/46/undo
Meta: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/users/46/undo

---

#### Accept

First: I'm quite honored that you would choose me as a not obnoxious, helpful user. Thanks! I shall strive to continue being not obnoxious and helpful.

This site is special. It needs and is going to need quite a bit more guidance than most sites. I don't have much experience moderating at all - I would need to learn on the job. I'm confident that I can figure it out with the help of the Community team and other mods, but it might take a few weeks.

I'm decently versed in the *standard* SE network, so I know a bit about how things work. Much of my knowledge about *policy* (mostly around close reasons), though, doesn't apply very well to this site. It's a learning experience for everyone. Especially me. Again, much learning required.

I was somewhat unsure as to whether to accept this at first. I really want to see this site succeed, for a number of different reasons, and I don't really know if I'm the best person to do it. I see it as a challenge, though, and I'll do my absolute best for the site if chosen, and my absolute best if not.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you'd like to nominate this user?

Comment: @gparyani he seems very helpful and not obnoxious even though he has a lot of reputation. On other forums, such as Apple Support Communities, the users with high reputation tend to be very obnoxious.

Comment: @Compukid you should [edit] that into your answer, as not everybody reads all comments (wait, this is a community wiki even... done :). Apart from that, I second what you wrote about Undo: that's exactly what I've noticed about him.

Comment: Thanks for all the nice comments! I'll accept, although there are those here that would probably be better. Also: if chosen, I will do my best to eliminate all obsolete/please-accept comments ;)

Comment: @undo You're running for [StackOverflow moderator](http://stackoverflow.com/election/5#post-21687291) elections, do you have enough time for both?

Comment: @Fract Absolutely - I have quite a lot of free time. I'm confident that (if asked) I could do both.

Answer (score 32):

I'd like to nominate [Gilles](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/64/gilles).

[image: profile for Gilles at Software Recommendations Stack Exchange, Q&A for people seeking specific software recommendations]

[[image: profile for Gilles at Software Recommendations Stack Exchange, Q&A for people seeking specific software recommendations]

[profile for Gilles on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/164368.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/164368)](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/users/64/gilles)

He's been very active on Meta, and all his answers are quite well thought out. He's also quite experienced on the network, and already a moderator on several sites (which is quite important on a site like this)

---

#### Conditional accept

I was a moderator on [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) for its first two years. Recommendations is a topic we struggled with. I'm also active on several computer tech sites ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), formerly on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), Unix & Linux and a few more). So yes, I can contribute experience.

I'm undecided whether to accept. I think this site can only succeed if it has serious quality control. Ideally, the community will naturally apply this quality control. As a user, I intend to vote to close questions that I consider too broad and flag answers that I consider too uninformative for deletion. If I become a moderator, I will apply this quality control, binding vote or not — I'd be heavier-handed than I've been on other sites.

I'm willing to spend the time and effort, but only if this site is going in (what I consider to be) the right direction, and only if I'm not doing it alone. We probably need 5 mods rather than the usual 3, and with an agreement to enforce quality controls.

Comment: @Gilles You may not be the moderator this site wants, but you're the moderator this site needs.

Comment: People (including yourself) say you have a hard hand. That is what this site needs, but what if something the community wants doesn't agree with your opinion? Do you use your hard hand for your opinion or what the community decides? If both, how do you decide which?

Comment: @Seth That depends on the nature of the something. For things like the site scope (e.g. whether games, hardware, websites are on-topic), it's entirely up to the community. For things like quality enforcement, I think mods should act if if nobody else does, and sometimes even go against the majority of the community. This goes especially on “presumed difficult” sites like [programmers.se] started out, or like this one.

Comment: Everybody looking up your posts on this new meta site knows that you have a clear vision of what the site should be. I can't think of a user more anxious to shape the site in the right directon.

Comment: Gilles Gilles Gilles.

Comment: I must agre from what I've seen you would be great.
If you become a moderator you can better work to **ensure** the site goes in the right direction.
(Your idea of a better direction coincides with mine, i think.)

Comment: This nomination is controversial. As of the instant that this comment was posted, there are +18 upvotes and -6 downvotes for a total score of 12.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with being controversial. This site is controversial. Gilles is a well established individual with the past experience and the track record to actually pull this off. Moderating this site is not going to be an easy task.

Comment: I wonder why I'm the first one who tries to explain the decision to downvote (maybe because people fear consequences?). I agree @Gilles has done excellent job on this site, but compared to current moderators (and moderators on other SE sites I have been active), I have found his approach too aggressive and pedantic (most probably this is just a cultural difference). YMMV, and that's why we have voting. The positive score speaks for itself.

Comment: @gparyani if you check both Undo and Gilles posts, you will notice that both has 25 upvotes with only 5 and 8 downvotes respectively. This is not controversial, strictly speaking. More controversial is Angelo appointment. BTW, controversial is not bad, actually is good. It means that the community feels strongly about something and are actively participating in the topic. I prefer a "controversial" post than just 0 or 1 vote and 0 comments.

Comment: @Gilles You won't be doing it alone. The SE team chooses 3 mod pro tem's, and they will also be assisting you once the site enters public beta and the mods are chosen.

Comment: @gparyani I know (I've already been a mod on 3 beta sites). Mods turn out to have varying levels of involvement, though. More importantly, even if it's “3 ♦ against the community” rather than “1 ♦ against the community”, it can't work: there has to be a sizable part of the community that wants the site to succeed.

Answer (score 21):

[image: profile for Journeyman Geek at Software Recommendations Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people seeking specific software recommendations]

[image: profile for Journeyman Geek at Software Recommendations Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people seeking specific software recommendations]
[profile for Journeyman Geek on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/343080.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/343080/journeyman-geek)

I'm self nominating myself, primarily cause I suspect the SU/Root Access crowd would do it anyway (or will nag me till I do). I'm just <strike>starting to get warmed up on obtaining mad reputation</strike> getting into things here, but I have significant reputation on Superuser, as well as a good working relationship with the mods there, on SF as well as AU. Considering that there's overlap, and we're going to have people telling people 'ask this at SR.SE, thats a pretty useful thing.

I'll leave it to others to describe how I meta moderate, simply cause they would see things I won't. I do try my best to be polite, and steer people in the right direction even if they're horribly wrong.

I've helped shape the current policy on [software recommendations on superuser](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6060/software-recommendations-what-software-can-do-this/6061#6061), amongst other things, and try to be active on meta. I've a decent idea how things *work* on stackexchange, and a very good grasp on the sites we're likely going to end up talking to when cross site moderation issues occur.

Here are my main [SR.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/125/journeyman-geek), [meta.SR.SE](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/users/125/journeyman-geek) and [SE network profiles](http://stackexchange.com/users/343080/journeyman-geek?tab=accounts)

Comment: You were previously the only one to be approved uncontroversially, until now. (+11 and -1 votes as of the instant that this was posted) By the way, I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: Yup. I noticed that too. I guess you can't win over everyone ;)

Answer (score 15):

I'd like to nominate **[Seth](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/86/seth)**

[image: profile for Seth at Software Recommendations Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people seeking specific software recommendations]

[image: profile for Seth at Software Recommendations Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people seeking specific software recommendations]
[profile for Seth on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1208323.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1208323/seth)

He's been a huge part of helping shape the community so far. He's said before that he would really need to think about it before accepting a nomination here, and I believe that the best mods are those that need to be (ever so gently) arm-twisted into it.

---

### Decline

I'd love to be a moderator here and help define our policies, but I feel I don't have the time that it is going to take to moderate this site well.

I am grateful for all the support that has been shown on my nomination.

Comment: @Seth I'd prefer that the styles of the titles be the same in all the answers (Undo set the precedent of the title style that I am using)

Comment: @gparyani I have a problem with "reject". I am not *rejecting* something, I am *declining* it. There is a difference. I don't see where Undo did anything.

Answer (score 11):

[image: profile for Caleb at Software Recommendations Stack Exchange, Q&A for people seeking specific software recommendations]
[image: profile for Caleb at Software Recommendations Stack Exchange, Q&A for people seeking specific software recommendations]
[profile for Caleb on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/120635.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/120635/caleb)

I first encountered Caleb on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1925/caleb) where he impressed me by the quality of his answers. He also has an impressive record of editing, flagging, leaving helpful comments and other positive contributions. He is very level-headed, and has amply demonstrated his ability to [moderate a difficult site](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/30/caleb) (starting as a nominated moderator during the beta phase, then going on to be elected). Caleb has already visibly contributed good answers and guidance on this site. If he is willing, he would be a great participant in the moderator team.

---

**Edit, Caleb Speaking...**

Thanks for the kind words and vote of confidence. I would consider accepting this post if –and only if– SE's vision for how this site should be moderated jives with my own. Obviously it is at their discretion to appoint *pro-tempore* moderators, so this is easy.

I foresee that this site is going to be a bug-bear to moderate. Frankly I'm not even 100% sold on the idea working, but it's worth a try. You can get a sense of what I think [questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/429/caleb?tab=questions) and [answers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/429/caleb?tab=answers) should look like [from my comments](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/429/caleb?tab=activity&sort=comments). I was traveling and missed most of the private beta, so I am late to the meta party, but still not afraid to [disagree](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/580/429). If a heavy hand is not kept on this site, I think it will get out of hand quickly. That means setting the minimum quality bar higher than most sites and enforcing it.

I have also been acting as a *pro-tem* on [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/) where our main challenge has been attracting enough attention that real experts got interested. To do this we have been babying along even low quality posters, helping them rewrite each individual question and answer. This has finally started to pay off as real experts have started participating, but it's been a long road. I'm not interested in that kind of time investment here as the subject matter is not of *that* much interest to me. I did the vision casting thing on Christianity (count [my meta posts](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/users/30/caleb?sort=votes)) and it takes a *lot* of time and brain cells to see clearly where things should go and then educate people into getting on board with going there. For this topic I would me more interested in playing bouncer.

I would be willing to take a post here if:

- There are to be more than the usual 3 mods.
- There are one or two others on the crew that are vision casters.<sup>1</sup>
- The need is for extra experienced hands to help enforce minimum standards.
- We are going to play hard ball with low quality stuff by…

  - …quickly closing questions that aren't up to snuff and leaving the impetus on OP's to fix them.
  - …outright deleting answers early rather that late that don't do what answers are supposed to do.

We joke around about mods being power hungry overlords. In this case I think it *should* be true in a sense. This isn't a time to play too nice. One can still be respectful and professional of course, but if you are looking for a mod to comment on all posts and say "Aww, there there now, you'll put more effort into following our guidelines next time right?" then I'm not your man.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Basically this needs to be a good-cop bad-cop routine and I'm mostly going to be into the latter. I suggest we need at least two of each.</sub>

---

Comment: I see @Gilles suggests more (five rather than three) mods, and that seems right and wise to me. Quite a different crowd gathering here than the coddled community at BH.SE! :)

Comment: As for your "good cop" counterpart, see my nomination :)

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to nominate [Izzy](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/185/izzy) ([meta profile](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/users/185/izzy)). He has been one of the most helpful and active users on this site since it started private beta, both in meta and on main. I think he would make a great moderator for this site.

[image]
 
[image]

[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1540386.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1540386)

---

### Accept

Eying the nominations since they've been brought to my attention approximately 2 weeks ago, I was tempted to go for it *and not to go for it* at the same time, so I don't take this easily. For one, being a mod, my votes to close/delete postings are binding as soon as I hit the button – and I'm rather the "community guy" who loves the peer principle used at SE for "normal users". Thankfully, there are always multiple mods, so not all of them must share the same strong points (as long as they complement each other to do so "in concert").

As pointed out in [Gilles' nomination post](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/222/185) (and the comments to it), I agree this site requires a "strong hand". That's probably not me. But a strong hand is not the only thing needed. Picking up [Caleb's cop example](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/606/185), as moderator I will rather play the "good cop". I was asked to candidate on the 2013 mod election at [Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/) for a.o. exactly that reason: being an intermediator, conciliate when two members collide, finding a consensus. Having *[Gilles](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/64/gilles)*, *[Caleb](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/users/429)*, or both (preferred!) on one side (and *[Undo](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/users/46)* on the other), I'm quite confident I can contribute my gifts.

I feel honored being nominated by you, and hope to live up to your expectations (should I be put on the post). I definitely want this site to succeed, which is why I put all my weight in here from the day I joined (and even set my "[regular site](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/16575/izzy)" back a little). Whether becoming a mod or (a) not, that goal stays, and I will do my very best to help reaching it.

---

<sup>Just minutes after I added my "conditional accept", *Gilles* and *Undo* have been placed into charge. So I feel I have to remove the "conditional" *from my end* :)</sup>

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to nominate myself.

[image: profile for Angelo Neuschitzer at Software Recommendations Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people seeking specific software recommendations]

[image: profile for Angelo Neuschitzer at Software Recommendations Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people seeking specific software recommendations]
[profile for Angelo Neuschitzer on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/472669.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/472669/angelo-neuschitzer)

I came to SO 2 1/2 years ago and after learning the rules there I soon started to read the questions and answers on meta to get a feeling on how such communities organize themselves.
When I read about the SW-Rec proposal I instantly committed myself because I thought this part to be missing on SO. Now here I flocked to meta more than to the main site at first and want to continue my active participation in the community building process (which I will, being moderator or not :))

My communication style is (usually) geared toward finding a consent or at least really trying to understand what the position of the participants are even if this takes its time.

Comment: @Voters Could any of you explain the downvotes? (I did not downvote.)

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but I would also like to hear the reason for downvoting.

Comment: I didn't downvote, (I haven't seen much of Angelo)
but if I were the downvoter, I would feel no need to explain myself. It isn't like a Answer where it would "-1 No Link" or "-1 That tool is really poor for this use case." 
It is going to be something more likely to offend eg: "I think he makes bad calls." or "I think he is biased" or "I think his vision for the site is poor."
Voting should be fairly anonymous

Comment: I agree with Oxinabox! But if someone wants to reason their downvotes I would be glad (then I can improve myself for the next moderator election)

Comment: +6 and -5 as of the instant that this comment was posted

Comment: @Oxinabox: the downvoting is anonymous however a comment just lets people improve - in some cases it should be couched in careful language to avoid offending true (and in those cases it is easier to skip) but still it is *nice* to hear reasoning

Answer (score 5):

[image: profile for juergen d at Software Recommendations Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people seeking specific software recommendations]

[image: profile for juergen d at Software Recommendations Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people seeking specific software recommendations]
[profile for juergen d on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/279943.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/279943/juergen-d)

I'd like to nominate juergen d, the original proposer of this site. In my eyes, he knows the best on how to moderate the site; otherwise, how would he have the audacity to propose it in the first place?

- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/135/juergen-d
- https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/users/135/juergen-d

---

### Decline

I would love to moderate this site, but I think we really need an experienced moderator who also has a lot of time to moderate it, which I currently don't have. Thank you very much for the nomination.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I don't know, but probably because you disqualify all other candidates with your statement?

Comment: I don't have anything against juergen, I don't even know him, but no one gets any special dibs on how a site is moderated or scope, etc. Even the person who proposed it.

Comment: I would love to moderate that site. But I think we really need an experienced moderator who also has a lot of time moderating the site which I currently would not have. But thanks for the nomination.