# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Software Recommendations's [first moderator election](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: Undo] [image: Izzy] [image: Nicolas Raoul]

They'll be replacing [the existing crew](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/608) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also join me in thanking Gilles and Journeyman Geek who did so much to help this site become so successful.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5705509592104960/0).

Comment: Yes! Thanks to Gilles and Journeyman for all their work (and future support during the "transition" etc). And thanks to the voters for participating and their trust we'll do our very best to not disappoint :)

Comment: Congratulations to the newly elected moderators. But the link to "the existing crew" reminds me to "link only posts" ... it already points to the NEW crew. Therefor consider replacing it with whatever to what "used to be that crew" ... Maybe a first "task" for any of the new crew members?

Comment: Congrats to  Izzy, Undo, & Nic

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for your great work helping to prove that this site could work, and make it work, Gilles and Journeyman Geek,

thank you for being willing to keep doing this work, Undo,

and congratulations on the election, Izzy, Nicolas Raoul, and Undo!

Answer (score 4):

Congrats Undo, Izzy, and Nicolas!

Thank you for all the time you volunteer!

Software Recommendations will continue to grow with this great team.